# Visa vignette/stamp unglued in passport. Staple or glue it back?

Tags: visas, passports, passport-stamps

A visa vignette in my passport has come unglued from the page in the passport. Should I reattach it by gluing or stapling it back to the page? Will doing it myself **invalidate** the visa? Are there some international visa/passport rules covering this.

Finally if I am allowed to do so, does it matter on which page I affix it? Since the page on which it was glued is free of stamps, I would rather reattach it to a different page so I can use the fresh page for stamps if that is allowable.

Comment: Visa of which country? I imagine Zimbabwe is going to be a lot less stringent than say the UK.

Comment: @JonathanReez I am curious however what informs that opinion? Sometimes the poorest countries are officially the strictest on certain issues.

Comment: I don't have any sources (yet - still at work) so I'm posting this as a comment, but I would strongly advise against *stapling* it back. I would assume gluing it back would be acceptable/not noticeable in most cases, but stapling it could potentially damage some of the security features and marking on the visa, not to mention, raise the suspicion of tampering. Still, overall I would say (if you have time) just play it safe and have it re-issued.

Comment: Zimbabwe might be officially strict but they probably lack the will to enforce their own rules.

Comment: What you are describing is a good way to invalidate the entire passport.

Comment: @JonathanReez how many times have you been to Zimbabwe?  Other African countries?

Comment: @phoog I'm not particularly sure about Zimbabwe itself - perhaps they are even more strict. But in any case it depends on who issued the visa in the first place.

Comment: `Should I reattach it by gluing or stapling it back to the page` I would refrain from doing any of that and check with the country issuing the visa ? Anyway I am curious as to how did the vignette come off ? They are stuck to the passport page, as if their life depended on it.

Comment: @DumbCoder It's a  long term visa and has been in the passport for years, over nine years. I was surprised it came off honestly but you know quality control sometimes fails so it could just be an outlier.

Comment: Over nine years? US passports expire after 10, how much longer is yours valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally play it safe and have it re-issued. Strongly advise against stapling it back. Gluing it back would probably be acceptable/not noticeable in most cases, however stapling it could potentially damage some of the security features and marking on the visa, not to mention, raise the suspicion of tampering.

If gluing, moving it to a different page is a no no. Many visas now have security numbers/alphabets at the bottom.

[image]

You never know if some of those numbers reference the page to which the visa was affixed and thereby invalidating it if moved.

Finally, doing anything to the visa/passport could be at the extreme be interpreted as mutilation which invalidates the whole passport and require replacement using the [US Department of State guidance](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/FAQs.html) as a example.

> If your passport has been significantly damaged, especially the book
>   cover or the page displaying your personal data and photo, you will
>   need to apply for a new passport. Damage that might require you to
>   replace your passport includes water damage, a significant tear,
>   unofficial markings on the data page, missing visa pages (torn out), a
>   hole punch, or other injuries.

Comment: Actually the machine readable zone is specified in the ICAO standard, and there is nothing relating to the page on which the visa is affixed.

Comment: @phoog There are optional figures in positions 29-44 whose formatting is unknown and could be tied to anything.